# Can Google and Apple read Telegram notifications's body?

Tags: encryption, google, apple, telegram

When using e2e encryption (secret chats), the answer is obviously no (I hope), but I am talking about NOT e2e-encrypted messages, the ones stored in the cloud.

I am of course aware that the messages are travelling on SSL encrypted connections, but are the body of the messages encrypted in any way when they reach Google/Firebase Cloud Message, APN and other 3rd party push notifications services?

In other words, if I send a message to Bob over a NON-secret chat, can Google, Apple, etc. read the body of the message I sent to him when it passes through their push notifications servers?

Comment: Unless it says somewhere that there is an extra layer of encryption for the messenger using the service, I would assume not. Depends on the specific service too. Voting as too broad.

Comment: The messenger in question is specifically the official Telegram client, and I would assume that the behaviour is the same for all platform's implementations, like it is for secret chats.